# Using value from one map as key in another map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map

I have a unordered_map AvailableRooms of hotels against number of rooms. Like

```
Sheridan -> 10
Marriot ->12
```

I have a map hotelOnDate which stores, string date converted to unix time against hotel.

```
142356789 -> Sheridan
142356749 -> Marriot
```

Now when I try to access the hotels unordered_map values using the map keys, I get a 0.

```
for(auto it = hotelOnDate.begin(); it != hotelOnDate.end(); it++){
        std::cout<<AvailableRooms[it->second]<<std::endl;
    }
```

AvailableRooms["Sheridan"] though gives the correct output 10.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: That will be 200 lines of code. I have reproduced the complete issue here.

Comment: Reduce your code to reproduce this behavior, I didn't ask you for posting your full code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? In particular, you should be interested in the value given by `it->second` when you access `AvailableRooms`. It may be helpful to put that to a temp variable, so it is easier to see in debugger, or just to print it out if you're not using a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same thing in my code and seems to work for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<std::string,std::string> mymap = {
                { "Mars", "g"},
                { "Saturn", "h"},
                { "Jupiter", "i" } };

 std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> imap = {{"g","1"},{"h","2"}}; 
 for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << it->first << ": " <<imap[ it->second ] << std::endl;
  }
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please compile this and check it on your end!